# AWS Ubuntu 16.04 PHP 7.0 fail to receive file upload error 1

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04

I am at the end of my rope here so here goes.
What I have tried? Everything! I have searched the forums for weeks looking for a solution. Our server is on AWS and it won't receive a file upload.

Yes, I have checked the PHP upload_max_filesize and it is set to 100MB.

Yes, I check the post_max_size is set to 100MB.

Yes, I have checked that the upload file is on.

Yes, the directory permissions are set correctly.

Yes, I have checked my phpinfo() and all the settings are showing there.

This is my test script (the short version).

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($_FILES);
    echo "</pre>";

    phpinfo();

    exit;
  }
```

After post the results are this:

```
array(1) {
      ["fileToUpload"]=>
      array(5) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(9) "badge.pdf"
      ["type"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["tmp_name"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["error"]=>
      int(1)
      ["size"]=>
      int(0)
    }
  }
```

The error message is always 1 and file that I am uploading is always 123 KB. The manual says http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

```
$phpFileUploadErrors = array(
    0 => 'There is no error, the file uploaded with success',
    1 => 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini',
    2 => 'The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form',
    3 => 'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded',
    4 => 'No file was uploaded',
    6 => 'Missing a temporary folder',
    7 => 'Failed to write file to disk.',
    8 => 'A PHP extension stopped the file upload.',
```

So the only conclusion is the the OS is not reading the PHP directive. 
How can I fix this?

I have several other web servers and none of them has done this ever.

UPDATE 1/6/2019:
I can upload a 98-byte file.

Comment: check `post_max_size` value.

Comment: post_max_size is set to 100MB

Comment: Fixed it. This enable_post_data_reading was off. Turned it on and everything works like it suppose to. Got the answer from here https://askubuntu.com/questions/909083/post-max-size-limit-changing-not-working